# Set nickname with emoji using official WhatsApi for PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, whatsapp

I want to add two emoji in the Nickname with WhatsAPI official library for PHP, to send a message.

```
$w = new WhatsProt($username,"MyNickname+SoccerBall+Pizza", true);
```

So I want that My Nickname will be display with the soccer ball and pizza emoji after that. How can I do this?

Comment: any possible solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the Unicode equivalent for the emoji.
You can find a table [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)